# Is this the correct implementation of merge sort?

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

```
def merge(arr1, arr2):
    returned = []
    while len(arr1) > 0 and len(arr2) > 0:
        if arr1[0] >= arr2[0]:
            returned.append(arr2[0])
            arr2.pop(0)
        else:
            returned.append(arr1[0])
            arr1.pop(0)
    if len(arr1) > 0:
        returned = returned + arr1
    if len(arr2) > 0:
        returned = returned + arr2
    return returned
```

Above is the merge function. Below is the merge sort function.

```
def merge_sort(nums):
    #print("Merge sorting following array:")
    #print(nums)
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return nums
    else:
        middle = int(len(nums)/2)
        first_half = nums[:middle]
        #print("First half is:")
        #print(first_half)
        second_half = nums[middle:]
        #print("Second half is:")
        #print(second_half)
        return merge(merge_sort(first_half), merge_sort(second_half))
```

It feels like something is off because I timed it using the time module, and it was about 4 times as fast as a bubble sort algorithm, on a list 10 numbers long. I think I may be overthinking the merge function, but cannot put my finger on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What makes you think that it's wrong? Have you tested it on larger input? Is the output correct?

Comment: Don't use pop(0) btw, it's very ineffective. If you pop the last element, it's exactly one operation. Popping the first one however forces the whole list to rearrange, so it is O(N), where N is the length of the list. This makes your merge function's complexity O(n^2), so it can be even slower than the bubble sort. You can always reverse the arr1 and arr2 (that's O(N)) and then pop from the back

Comment: But also note, timing your implementations on a list of size 10 is not going to give you very meaningful results.

Comment: @Maras What do you mean with "can be even slower than the bubble sort"? Bubble sort is O(n^2) as well, and its hidden constant is much larger (the shifting of `pop(0)` is done at very high speed).

Comment: @Maras would it work to index the list instead? arr1 = arr1[1:] ?

Comment: @superb rain With that, mergesort's complexity is O(n^2 log n), that is slower than bubble sort. In addition, it has much larger constant.

Comment: @dgoodie Yes, but you need to take everything from the back of the lists then. Reversing the list is O(N) and then popping the last element is O(1), so it will be fine.

Comment: pop() from the front is a slow operation. A common way to implement an optimized top down merge sort, is to do a one time allocation of a temp array, a one time copy of the original array into the temp array, then alternate the direction of merge with each level of recursion, as shown in the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation). Note that most libraries use some hybrid variation of bottom up merge sort and insertion sort.

Comment: @Maras It's not just O(n^2 log n) but O(n^2). And it has a much *smaller* constant. Feel free to optimize bubble sort so that it's not [over 120 times slower](https://preview.tinyurl.com/y6cvakxl) on a list of 5000 numbers. Let me know how far you get.

Comment: @dgoodie: You can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is mostly functional, but it has some shortcomings:

- it cannot handle an empty list: such an argument will cause an infinite recursion resulting in a **stack overflow**. You should test if the length is <= 1.
- the merge function modifies its arguments by popping the first element repeatedly. This is likely a very costly approach. It would be more efficient to use index variables to iterate in `arr1` and `arr2`.
- it does not implement a stable sort as equal elements are taken first from `arr2` then from `arr1`.

Here is an alternative you can time and compare:

```python
def merge(arr1, arr2):
    result = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(arr1) and j < len(arr2):
        if arr1[i] <= arr2[j]:
            result.append(arr1[i])
            i = i + 1
        else:
            result.append(arr2[j])
            j = j + 1
    return result + arr1[i:] + arr2[j:]

def merge_sort(nums):
    if len(nums) <= 1:
        return nums
    else:
        middle = len(nums) >> 1
        first_half = nums[:middle]
        second_half = nums[middle:]
        return merge(merge_sort(first_half), merge_sort(second_half))
```